How much energy is transfered from one step to the ground by average person?
So basically all in title: I want to know how much energy typical (80 kg) person transfers to the ground with each step (not running, not crawling, just walking)

There are different ways this could be answered. If you scuff your feet, friction heats the ground. I will just consider that as you walk, you go up and down a little. With each step your leg pushes you and the earth apart. This makes you move a little, giving you kinetic energy. The earth also moves, but so little that it would be impossible to measure the tiny kinetic energy it gains.

The answer may be less than you think. Walking is a very efficient mode of movement, your body's centre of mass moves up and down by a very small amount if walking on firm, level ground (less than $10$ cm per step), and the muscles in your calves store potential energy as they stretch, releasing it in the next step, and reducing the overall energy expenditure.
This steps-to-calories calculator gives a figure of about $0.045$ kcal per step for a $80$ kg human, which is about $200$ joules per step - but we should subtract the basic metabolic rate (BMR) from this to get the actual energy expended per step. Assuming a BMR of $80$ joules per second and a walking rate of two steps per second then the additional energy above BMR expended in walking is about $160$ joules per step.

160 sound like a awful lot. It's like a bullet hit.
